# How do I create a file based on the date?

Tags: c#, .net, file

```
    string filename = DateTime.Today.ToString() + ".csv";
    if(!File.Exists(filename))
        File.Create(filename);
```

I thought this would work but it throws a 'format not supported' error. I just want a csv to be created in the directory alongside my .exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `DateTime.Today.ToString()` contains slashes, which are not valid as part of a windows filename.

You can, however, do this: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that converting a DateTime to a string will generate a string with invalid filename characters, such as colons (:) and that will cause the create to fail.

You may want to use a format string to control the generated filename. e.g.

```
string filename = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".csv";
```

Comment: The colons and slashes are both invalid characters.

Comment: Doesn't colon select an alternate NTFS stream?

Comment: Why replace when you can explicitly format in the first place?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you can create an alternate data stream unless the main file stream already exists.

Comment: The replace is a very bad way of doing this, that doesn't translate between all locales. A custom format specifier is the *right* way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your locale has `/` / `:` (or similar confusing characters) in the date format. You should specify an explicit format - `"yyyy MM dd"` for example:

```
string filename = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy MM dd",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".csv";
```

Comment: Won't `yyyy` just be setting your self up for a Y10k bug?  ;-)

Comment: @David - yes, that is deliberate - come 9995, I'll get all the consultancy contracts for fixing it; mwahahahah.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody has pointed out, the default DateTime.ToString() formatting has invalid characters in it (for just about any region settings), so that

```
string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".csv";
```

generates a 'filename' like `2/18/2011 4:26:48 PM.csv` -- which is invalid

if you want a date-time based name, try

```
string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".csv";
```

to get something like `2011021804254.csv`

you can add more formatting, just as long as it doesn't contain any of the following: `\ / : * ? " < > |`

Answer (score 0):

Your date has slashes in it, try this instead

```
string filename = Datetime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".csv";
```